# How to reverse values in x-axis - excel 2016

Tags: excel

Please can you help me to reverse the values of the x-axis I have? I need to draw the curve in MS excel 2016 (x-axis starts with 4000 and descends to zero not from zero to 4000).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dim revs as variant, i as long

with worksheets("sheet1")
    revs = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).values
    for i = lbound(revs, 1) to ubound(revs, 1)
        revs(i, 1) = revs(ubound(revs, 1) - i, 1)
    next i
    .cells(2, "A").resize(ubound(revs, 1), 1) = revs
end with
```

The subtraction may be out by 1 but you should be able to rectify that.